# how to setOnClickListener in TextInputLayout

Tags: java, android

```
ttilLastDate = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tilLastDate);
tilLastDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("PublishTask","has click");
            }
        });
```

why the OnClickListener don't work?

Comment: Could you xml where is TextInputLayout?

Comment: try using setOnTouchListener rather than setOnClickListener. On a second thought have you set android:clickable="true" on your TextInputLayout??

Comment: check if it works when u click second time

Comment: @SandeepBhandari setOnClickListener automatically enables clickable

Comment: your TextInputLayout should be having an edit text in it you can set clicklistener on it

Comment: @VivekMishra i have an editText in TextInputLayout ,but if i set clicklistener  on editText ,the listener works when i click second time.

Comment: @Mann yes,but why?

Comment: @MiguelBenitez TextInputLayout in LinearLayout

Comment: @ZhangHuayan, So, does it work when you click second time ?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and my solution was to use the **setOnFocusChangeListener on the EditText** inside the TextInputLayout.

This is an example using [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/).

The Layout:

```
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

The listener:

```
@OnFocusChange(R.id.edit_text)
public void actionOnEditText(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus)
        yourClickMethod();
}
```